# Android : how to play a sound on external display

Tags: java, android, audio, external-display

I would like to play a sound (mp3, wav...) on external display (as HDMI for example). I have tried with the `RingtoneManager` but I can't specify the device.

I have try this [Android force HDMI audio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31909040/1235698) without success.

I can do this with adb like this:

```
adb.exe shell tinyplay path_of_my_song -D 1 -p 768 -n 8
```

The option `-D 1` specified the device. But how can i do this programmatically in java?

Comment: Can you not simply run the same adb command via Java using _Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)_ ?